# Is Task.ContinueWith() guaranteed to run?

Tags: c#, async-await, task

Suppose I have some async task that can sometimes run fast and sometimes slow,

```
public Random seed = new Random();
private async Task<string> _Work()
{
    int time = seed.Next(0, 5000);
    string result = string.Format("Worked for {0} milliseconds", time);
    await Task.Delay(time);
    return result;
}

public void SomeMethod()
{
    _Work(); // starts immediately? Am I right?

    // since _Work() will be executed immediately before ContinueWith() is executed,
    // will there be a chance that callback will not be called if _Work completes very quickly,
    // like before ContinueWith() can be scheduled?
    _Work().ContinueWith(callback)
}
```

Is the callback in Task.ContinueWith() guaranteed to run in the above scenario?

Comment: Why do you think `callback` won't be called if `_Work` completes very quickly?

Comment: @EricLippert yes, suppose SomeMethod() is called many times in another part of the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> will there be a chance that callback will not be called if _Work completes very quickly?

No. Continuations passed to `ContinueWith` will always be scheduled. If the task is already complete, they will be scheduled immediately. The task uses a thread-safe kind of "gate" to ensure that a continuation passed to `ContinueWith` will always be scheduled; there is a race condition (of course) but it's properly handled so that the continuation is always scheduled regardless of the results of the race.